Scanning 12M entries to fetch few records
We have few keys stored with pattern “server.overview.map:”. Now we want to get all records for the above pattern.
We are using SCAN command to do so. On production we have 12M entries and only 180 entries with above pattern. So SCAN command will scan 12M entries to just get 180 entries. Also since SCAN has default count to 10, it takes long to search above pattern in 12M entries.
We can use SCAN with high counts like 10,000, but we want to know how it will impact on CPU?
We can store keys for above pattern in a set, and then get all keys from set. But this will add more storage as for some other pattern we may have more than 1M entries.
We can use KEY command but it might have impact on CPU.
So we need to know what can be the best solution for this case.

With so many keys, KEYS may just block your server forever.
Are you using cluster or standalone?
I hope Cluster.
If cluster is the case - you can save all those keys with {hash_tag} meaning  {server.overview.map}:... for example.
That's promise you that all keys will go to the same slot.
Then you can do - CLUSTER KEYSLOT {server.overview.map}:one_of_the_keys (link contains also info about hashtag) that will return the slot own those keys.
Having the slot use CLUSTER COUNTKEYSINSLOT slot to get the count, and finally CLUSTER GETKEYSINSLOT slot count.
In response to comment:
First - search is for sure not the right direction, the performance and memory cost of indexing is far more expensive of the other solutions, and the search is efficient in complex searching but more overhead than simple scanning.
It was created to support queries like search in text etc. but not for simple scan.
I based my answer on:

On production we have 12M entries and only 180 entries with above pattern.

Yes, using a hashtag will distribute those keys to the same shard, but those are comparably a tiny number of keys, so it won't affect anything.
In addition to my previous offer, I think that if the pattern you provide to SCAN includes a hash_tag, it will know to scan just the relevant slots; hence you won't need all the commands above, but just to use the hash_tag in the pattern.
While saying that, ill say that scanning a cluster is tricky, since it really depends on the client implementations.
Redis/Valkey doesn't support cluster-wide scanning, and those are implemented by client libraries. In Valkey it's under development and discussions, but still not there.
Some libraries do it better, some worse.
I implemented it for Valkey-Glide, and we do it good, but it's a complex feature.
I don't think any of the clients support scanning cluster-wide base on a hashtag, so they will probably end up checking each shard once and moving to the other.
The overhead here depends on the cluster size.
If this is the size of keys out of 12M, stay with the hashtag.
If you want to make it more distributed, use a few different hashtags, but again, if this is the relation between the keys you really don't need it.
And if you would like to have cluster-wide based on a hashtag, you're welcome to Glide issues, I will be probably the first to answer, and we're highly prioritizing user requests.
And in any case, you are invited to visit, take a look and further ask anything you want.

Thanks for the response. Yes we are using cluster. But using hashtag will not create issue in distributing keys in multiple shards equally?
We have many keys with same pattern and it will result in add all those keys in same shard. Wdyt? Will Redis search engine can be useful?
Last option to store all keys in a Set and use it to get all keys.

Editing my answer with response
